# Connect to VPS through SSH

Tags: vps

Usually I bought VPS on Linode or DigitalOcean, the service provider allow me using ssh login by username and password.

But this time I changed another service provider, they tell me I can login through root account like `root@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx`, But when I try it, the terminal tell me

> Connection closed by xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx port 22

it doesn't give me a chance to input password.

But they give me a servers's ECDSA fingerprint

> SHA256:TrXrn0KF......

Should I do something with the fingerprint ? How can I access my VPS in Mac and Windows ?

Comment: *127.0.0.1* means your PC (*localhost*). That’s not where you’ll find your VPS, obviously. Look for its IP address.

Comment: @DaielB, I just give an example..

Answer (score -1):

Everything is explain [here](https://www.linode.com/docs/getting-started#connecting-to-your-linode-via-ssh).

In particular there is a note after the step 4 which precise that if you recently rebuild an existing Linode, you have to remove the pre-existing keys. On Windows you need to go in the registery with regedit (don't forget to save the registery before) and delete the appropriate key in :

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\SimonTatham\PuTTY\SshHostKeys
```